# How do you perform a solr sql select * statement?

Tags: sql, solr

This seems like a very simple question, but I have searched google for a long time and have not found any answers.

Specifically I am running into an issue performing a very simple select * sql query using Solr 6.5.0.

- **Q:** What am I trying to achieve?

  - **A:** Use Solr sql unlimited select statement to select all records in my collection that have "property_1" == 100
- **Q:** What issue am I running into?

  - **A:** When performing the query I receive an error saying "java.io.IOException: score is not a valid field for unlimited queries."
- **Q:** How do I prevent solr from automatically scoring my sql query (I don't care about the score) so I can perform an unlimited sql query and get back all fields in the documents I want?

  - **A:** ????

When I perform a solr sql query for all documents in my collection it fails because solr automatically includes a score field in the results and the score field cannot be used in unlimited sql queries. The thing is that my collection does not have a "score" field in it and I did not ask for the results to be scored. From googling around it would seem I get a score field by default from solr, but my reading would suggest that I should only get this if I requested it in my query (which I did not do).

I am using the Solr admin UI to perform the sql query. The following is the exact error message I get:

```
stmt=select * from TestIndex where property_1 = '100'"

{
  "result-set":{
    "docs":[{
        "EXCEPTION":"Failed to execute sqlQuery 'select * from TestIndex 
where property_1 = '100'' against JDBC connection 'jdbc:calcitesolr:'.\nError 
while executing SQL \"select * from TestIndex where property_1 = '100'\": 
java.io.IOException: score is not a valid field for unlimited queries.",
        "EOF":true,
        "RESPONSE_TIME":172}]}}
```

Now here is the same query except instead of using the above query, I replace the "select *" part with "select FieldA" and get all the records containing "FieldA". This query produces the following result which proves the unlimited sql select works

```
stmt=select FieldA from TestIndex where property_1 = '100'"

    {
  "result-set":{
    "docs":[{
        "FieldA":["AAAA"]}
      ,{
        "FieldA":["AAAA"]}
      ,{
        "FieldA":["AAAA"]}
      ,{
        "EOF":true,
        "RESPONSE_TIME":247}]}}
```

The problem is that I want all fields returned not just FieldA so the above query is useless to me. Also, this is just a POC. In a real world use case specifying all the fields in the sql statement is unrealistic. I would expect the * to work and it seems it would if Solr did not automatically try to provide a score in the unlimited results. So performing the following sql query, while it works, will not be realistic in a real world scenario.

```
stmt=select FieldA, FieldB, FieldC, FieldD from TestIndex where property_1 = 
'100'
```

To make things very simple my test collection has 6 documents in it. The following are all the documents. I used the non sql solr /select handler to get this result to show here (which BTW I would expect to be able to perform a solr sql select * to produce the same results as the solr /select *:* like below):

```
{
    "responseHeader":{
    "zkConnected":true,
    "status":0,
    "QTime":0,
    "params":{
        "q":"*:*",
        "indent":"on",
        "wt":"json",
        "_":"1494587051946"}},
    "response":{"numFound":6,"start":0,"docs":[
    {
        "FieldA":["AAAA"],
        "FieldB":["BBBB"],
        "FieldC":["CCCC"],
        "FieldD":["DDDD"],
        "dateTimestamp":1494591988400,
        "property_1":100,
        "_version_":1567193288840052736},
        {
            "FieldA":["AAAA"],
            "FieldB":["BBBB"],
            "FieldC":["CCCC"],
            "FieldD":["DDDD"],
            "dateTimestamp":1494591988403,
            "property_1":100,
            "_version_":1567193289014116352},
        {
            "FieldA":["AAAA"],
            "FieldB":["BBBB"],
            "FieldC":["CCCC"],
            "FieldD":["DDDD"],
            "dateTimestamp":1494591988404,
            "property_1":100,
            "_version_":1567193289034039296},
        {
            "FieldA":["AAAA"],
            "FieldB":["BBBB"],
            "FieldC":["CCCC"],
            "FieldD":["DDDD"],
            "dateTimestamp":1494591995474,
            "property_1":200,
            "_version_":1567193296256630784},
        {
            "FieldA":["AAAA"],
            "FieldB":["BBBB"],
            "FieldC":["CCCC"],
            "FieldD":["DDDD"],
            "dateTimestamp":1494591995475,
            "property_1":200,
            "_version_":1567193296265019392},
        {
            "FieldA":["AAAA"],
            "FieldB":["BBBB"],
            "FieldC":["CCCC"],
            "FieldD":["DDDD"],
            "dateTimestamp":1494591995476,
            "property_1":200,
            "_version_":1567193296267116544}]
}}
```

Sorry for the long post. I tried to give all the details.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

[According to the docs for ParallelSQL](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Parallel+SQL+Interface) (which is an experimental feature at the moment):

> The * syntax to indicate all fields is not supported in either limited or unlimited queries.

.. this seems to indicate that it's not related to score being computed, but just that issuing * is not possible.

*My guess* is that a JDBC driver / SQL implementation needs to know the names of each column before returning data - and when you're asking for all fields, new field names can show up at the document ranked as 1m - so the SQL interface would either to iterate over the result set twice - once to get all the field names and then once to get the documents (but the documents could have changed until the second request unless you lock the DB .. which wouldn't be performant), or cache everything in memory while reading it .. which wouldn't work for large datasets.

Comment: I did read the page you referenced but assumed it was old info because when trying the query with version 6.4 the request just our right failed. With 6.5 the request was excepted and it seemed that would have been streamed back if not for the score field. Thanks for the response

Answer (score 0):

Support for "SELECT *" was added recently, per https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-8847
However, it currently only works for LIMITed queries.